# connecting to mongodb from a container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, containers

I was unable to connect to mongodb container from my node app even with the connection string given from the official documentation

------the docker compose code:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

---connection to mongodb code:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Connected = async ()=>{
   try{
   await mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/test',
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
  );
  console.log("connected!!");
  
   }catch(err){
       console.log(err.message);
   }

}
Connected();
```

Comment: Have you tried to add an explicit entry for the ports of the mongo service in the docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: You could also try to add a `depends_on: ${DATABASE_NAME}` entry in your express service.

Comment: Try to add `depends_on: mongo` field for your '"mongo-express"

Comment: i tried to add depends_on: mongo but i got this error message: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to resolve the name like this, you need to set the name as a container name in your compose file. I have attached a working example you can use here:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

Comment: still getting the same error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo

Comment: Which version of Docker do you use?

Comment: my client version as well as server version is : 20.10.12

Comment: Strange. I can start it up, and open the URL: `http://localhost:8081` and then browse the MongoDB instance. Can you please try to run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` ?